# DefaultUriBuilderFactory in 5.1.0.RC3 no longer encodes space in queryParam() value

Tags: spring, spring-web

I see that Spring Web 5.1.0.RC3 changed the DefaultUriBuilderFactory default EncodingMode from URI_COMPONENT to TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES.

With this change, I found that when I call, for example, on a UriBuilder instance from the DefaultUriBuilderFactory:

```
uriBuilder.queryParam( "displayValue", "31.135, -108.06222222222222" ).build()
```

the resulting URI contains the raw space from the value argument:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8573/v1/own/position/probe?displayValue=31.135, -108.06222222222222
```

and thus my WebClient.get() call fails with an IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query.

In version 5.0.9.RELEASE with the default mode URI_COMPONENT, the space was encoded to a %20, and thus the WebClient HTTP GET succeeded.

Is this the expected behavior in mode TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES, and thus if I keep my DefaultUriBuilderFactory in that mode should I pre-encode the Strings before passing them to method queryParam( String, Object...)?

I find it hard to tell if this is the expected behavior from the javadoc on TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES, because it does not mention encoding the "component values," as opposed to the javadoc on URI_COMPONENT which does mention it.